# Gain of wireless antenna? (-3, 0, 3, 6)

Tags: antenna, wifi, gain

I read somewhere that each time the signal strength doubles, the gain in dB increases by 3.

So because it says each time it doubles, it has to start from somewhere, it means 0 db should have some strength? So if that's true then we should still have some strength even at -3dB, right?

- So do we have any signal strength at all at 0 dB? If we are e.g. one feet away from antenna can we receive anything?
- How does 2.4GHz (IEEE 802.11b) frequency and 5GHz (IEEE 802.11A) play any difference in this?
- I know that when you work with lower frequencies like 2.4 you can carry the signal further, so how does that make difference?
- How do you calculate your carrier strength in terms of distance by having two parameters of frequency and gain(dB), and I am talking about directional antennas?
  Like this one on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06Y2JH7PV) 5GHz and 23dBi, how far can laptops receive data with this? And how can you [scheme](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/support/docs/wireless-mobility/wireless-lan-wlan/82068-omni-vs-direct6.gif) the antenna propagation pattern?

Comment: sort of an answer to question 1 is this table at this link in the middle,https://www.metageek.com/training/resources/wifi-signal-strength-basics.html

Answer (score 3):

Decibel, or dB, is a measure for a *relation* of two parameters. \$ Decibel = 10 \cdot log\frac{P}{P_0}\$, with \$P_0\$ beeing the parameter you compare your signal with.

For calculating the gain of an antenna, you compare the recievable power at some point with the recievable power at that same point when a simple dipole antenna is used. When the power in both cases is the same (so there is no gain), than the \$\frac{P}{P_0} = 1\$. The log of 1 is 0. So 0 dB means, the antenna has no gain *compared to a dipole antenna*. -3 dB means, the antenna is producing half the power of a dipole antenna at the point where you measure.

To give an absolute measure of power in dB you use dBm. This stands for *decibel compared to 1 mW*, so you have \$P_0 = 1\ \text{mW}\$. 3 dBm would be double that of 1 mW => 2 mW. And -10 dBm would be 0.1 mW = 100 μW.

Regarding your question about lower and higher frequencies:

There is a concept called *free-space path loss*, which is changing with signal frequency. Also the effect you mentioned with 2.4 and 5 GHz WLAN is due to longer wavelengths (or lower frequencies) having a lower attenuation. That's why you receive a 2.4 GHz signal even in the next room, while 5 GHz is blocked quite strongly.

To calculate the received signal strength with a directional antenna you calculate the overall gain/attenuation of the signal path. This includes the output of the power amplifier, the gain of the sending antenna, the attenuation in air and the gain of the receiving antenna. With all values in dB you can just add them (with gains being positive, attenuations being negative).

\$P_{recieved} = P_{send} + G_{send} + FSPL + G_{recieve} \$